# RXjs canceling debounce from source

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm learning Rx so i dont get quiet well some of the mechanics on Rx, what i want to do i can do it easly with callbacks, but i want to understand Rx.

So what i want to do is, debounce a mouse over event 500ms and show a ui interface, and on mouse out hide that interface, so i have this code:

```
var outStream = Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern(
          function add (h) {
            asset.events.onInputOut.add(function(){
                h('out');
            });
          }
        );

        var overStream = Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern(
          function add (h) {
            asset.events.onInputOver.add(function(e){
                h('over');
            });
          }
        ).debounce(500);


        var source = Rx.Observable.merge(overStream, outStream);

        source.subscribe(function (x) {
            console.log(x);
          });
```

What i want is something like this:

```
.
.mouse over fired after 500ms
.mouseout
.
.mouse over
.mouse out fired before 500ms trigger cancel mouse over
```

I need some directions, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have my code on github link: https://github.com/eralha/angular-phaser/blob/master/js/src/modules/game/classes/camera.js#L78

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
var hoverStream = overStream.flatMapLatest(function() {
  return Rx.Observable.timer(500).takeUntil(outStream).map(function() { return 'hover'; })
});
```

This says "map each overStream element into an observable that will yield a single element after 500ms, but stop listening if outStream yields an element before it arrives". For this to work properly you'll need to remove the `debounce` from your overStream (and just keep it as a simple stream of all such events).

You could then merge the values into whatever result stream you wanted.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, link for the code: https://github.com/eralha/angular-phaser/blob/master/js/src/modules/game/classes/camera.js#L86

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you <3.